# Layers on top with dynamic width, alternatives other than position: absolute

Tags: html, css

The only way I know to get a layer on top is to use position: absolute.

[image]

(top good, bottom bad)

Once you do that you pretty much lose the option to scale dynamically with the rest of the page.

Sure you can do some `width: calc(62% - 60px);` hacking and get it almost there, or you can write a script that calculates the size etc..

But is there really no way to have a layer on top and still have it scaling with the page?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible with `position:relative;` Relatively positioned elements takes the width of parent & can be bring on top by using `z-index`. `z-index` is applicable only on **positioned** elements.

**Sample Code:**

```css
.menuParent{
height:34px;border:1px solid black;
}
.menu{
width:100%;position:relative;border:1px solid red;top:34px;z-index:1;background: white;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:120px;"  class="menuParent">
  <div class="menu">
    <div>AirBnb</div>
    <div>Booking.com</div>
    <div>Expedia
      <div>Agents</div>
    </div>ThaiHome</div>
</div>
<div> Other div below the menu list</div><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div style="width:240px;"class="menuParent">
  <div class="menu">
   <div>AirBnb</div>
    <div>Booking.com</div>
    <div>Expedia
      <div>Agents</div>
    </div>ThaiHome</div>
    </div>
    <div> Other div below the menu list width bigger width</div>
```

Comment: I actually tried your suggestion before, the problem is that it will expand all parent layers when you use relative - have a look:  https://db.tt/KBfNU2by4k

Comment: Could you share your DOM structure to understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
parent{
position: relative;
}

child {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.